# Append column df values to another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have one df

df1:

```
| Index | data1 |
|:---- |:------:|
| t5  | 0    | 
| t8  | 0    |
| t10  | 1    |
| t50  | 3    |
| t55  | 5    |
.
.
.
```

And i have another df

df2:

```
| Index | data2 |
|:---- |:------:|
| 1  | 2011/5/5    | 
| 2  | 2011/5/6    |
| 3  | 2011/5/7    |
| 4  | 2011/5/8    |
| 5  | 2011/5/9    |
| 6  | 2011/5/10    |
| 7  | 2011/5/11    |
| 8  | 2011/5/12    |
| 9  | 2011/5/13    |
| 10  | 2011/5/14    |
.
.
.
```

I want to append values of df2['data2'] to df1 like this:

index of df1 = t5 with Index of df2 = 5
index of df1 = t8 with Index of df2 = 8

Result:
df1:

```
| Index | data1 | data2 |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| t5  | 0    | 2011/5/9 |
| t8  | 0    | 2011/5/12 |
| t10  | 1    | 2011/5/14 |
.
.
etc, etc
```

I'll appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `df2`'s index format and then use [`pandas.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('t' + df2.index.astype(str)))
#       data1      data2
#Index                  
#t5         0   2011/5/9
#t8         0  2011/5/12
#t10        1  2011/5/14
```

Note that when you use [`pandas.DataFrame.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on `df2` you get:

```
df2.set_index('t' + df2.index.astype(str))
#           data2
#Index           
#t1      2011/5/5
#t2      2011/5/6
#t3      2011/5/7
#t4      2011/5/8
#t5      2011/5/9
#t6     2011/5/10
#t7     2011/5/11
#t8     2011/5/12
#t9     2011/5/13
#t10    2011/5/14
```

So you can join it with `df1` directly.